# Xamarin Mobile MediaPickerController Error after Migration to Unified API

Tags: ios, xamarin

I just migrate my Xamarin iOS app to Xamarin Unified using the Migration Tool.
The code below was working fine and the app didn’t have any error or warning before the migration.
After the migration I got the following errors
Error-1
PresentViewController doesn’t accept the MediaPickerController object as a parameter.
Error-2
mediaPickerController doesn’t have the method DismissViewController

```
        protected void TakePicture()
    {
        MediaPickerController mediaPickerController = mediaPicker.GetTakePhotoUI(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Name =  this.PictureName + ".jpg",
            DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear
        });
        if (!mediaPicker.IsCameraAvailable)
        {
            ShowUnsupported();
        }


//Error-1
        PresentViewController(mediaPickerController, true, null);
        try
        {
            mediaPickerController.GetResultAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                BTProgressHUD.Show("Processing");
                // Dismiss the UI yourself
//Error-2
                mediaPickerController.DismissViewController(true, () =>
                {
                    if (t.IsCanceled || t.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        BTProgressHUD.Dismiss();
                        return;
                    }
                    MediaFile file = t.Result;
                    FinishedPickingMedia(file);
                    BTProgressHUD.Dismiss();
                });


            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Insights.Report(ex, ReportSeverity.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest Xamarin.Mobile dll from here https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.mobile and reference the lib/ios-unified/Xamarin.Mobile.dll instead of the old dll.
This will fix the errors.